# "Not Enough Memory available" exception while running windows phone 8.1 emulator

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

"Windows Phone Emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running : 
Not Enough memory is available in the system to start an emulator that uses 2048 MB of startup RAM"

I am a beginner to Windows Phone App developement.I was trying to Deploy a Hub App template and while executing the code for the emulator I got the above error message! Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably its because your machine does not hove enough RAM? acording to this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911380) there are some workarounds.

> Follow the steps in this section carefully. Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, back up the registry for restoration in case problems occur.
>
> To work around this problem in a system that is running many programs that are using lots of memory, try to close those programs and then restart the emulator.
>
> If the emulator still does not start, you can disable the Hyper-V runtime memory monitoring functionality by adding a MemoryReserve registry. To do this, follow these steps:
> Start Registry Editor.
> Locate the following registry subkey:

```
>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization
```

Right-click the Virtualization folder, point to New, and then click DWORD Value..
Type MemoryReserve, and then press Enter.
Double-click MemoryReserve, enter 2048 in the Value data box, select the Decimal option, and then click OK.
Close Registry Editor.
In systems that experience this problem and that have fewer than 8 GB of RAM installed, a MemoryReserve value of 2048 (2 GB) is recommended. A value of zero (0) causes this registry setting to be ignored.

> Note You must restart the computer for this registry setting to take effect.

If this doesnt help give some more info about your machine haracteristics.

Also you can check this [article](https://guido1993.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/how-to-overcome-the-2-gb-ram-limit-on-android-visual-studio-2015-emulators/)

Comment: I have already tried this workaround before, following the link in the exception generated; even before posting this question ! Thnx for replying, by the way !